# How can I add custom menu item to window system menu under X?

Tags: x11, window-managers

I would like to add my custom command, to a window system menu (the one usually on the left top on titlebar, usually containing Minimize, Maximize and so on), and respond to it in my application.
In ms windows one can do

```
   HMENU hMenu = GetSystemMenu(hwnd, false);
   AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_STRING, ...)
```

Is something like this possible under X11? If not a general method maybe a solution for some specific window manager?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after your last edit, what I understand is that you want to add your custom menu to the menu that's on the *window decoration*, which is controlled by the *Window Manager*.

I don't think that's possible, although I'm not sure. I believe you should read the ICCCM and the EWMH to find if this is possible or not:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-Client_Communication_Conventions_Manual
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Window_Manager_Hints

Or you can send an email to wm-spec-list asking:

- http://mail.gnome.org/mailman/listinfo/wm-spec-list

Also, adding an option there makes it quite hidden, doesn't it? I guess most people don't ever click that menu... I don't even think that menu exists on all the possible Window Managers. You should really try to put your menu inside your application's Window instead of the Window Manager's decoration. Some environments don't even have Window Managers: what would your users do in this case?

Note that some applications (like the Chromium browser) don't use the Window Manager decorations: they implement their own decoration, they implement their own close/maximize/minimize buttons. This way, they have complete control over all the decoration buttons and menus, but their decoration doesn't have the same "look and feel" of the rest of the desktop. You could think about doing this, but I wouldn't encourage that... You should probably put your menu somewhere else (where it's not *that* hidden...).

Comment: We have that item added to menu on Windows and just wanted the same functionality under X11, it seems that only possible way for it is patching some window manager, which is not the way I prefer to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to add your app to the system menu?

I believe most modern desktop environments implement the XDG Menu Standard:
http://standards.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/menu-spec-latest.html

You'll have to learn other standards too probably:
http://standards.freedesktop.org/

They're all somehow short, so they won't consume more than some hours to read and learn.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more clear which menu I am asking about.

Comment: @Roman that's the one I was talking about, so I guess my answer is still valid. Take a look at the spec and check if that's what you need.

Comment: I cannot see a word about it there. I have edited the question again to make it even more clear what menu I am asking about.